# How to make a panel page the default local task

Tags: panels, routes

I've got a custom module providing local tasks like entity/%/edit and I'm trying to get entity/% to show up as the default local task. entity/% is defined as a Panel Page using the panels module. How do I do this? Whenever I change the menu type to "local task" or "menu tab" (or "default menu tab") the local tasks disappear from the display. This is in Drupal 7.14 with ctools 7/x-1/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was eventually able to get this to work. The page needed to be a "default menu tab" with the path `entity/%/view` or similar. With that, `entity/%` loads the path `entity/%/view` and all of the tabs show up as expected. This turned out to be more a problem with my understanding of default local tasks than anything else.

Comment: yeah, the trick is that for a default menu task (or tab) you need to add an extra argument onto the end of the url for the page you expect to see, so entity/%/foo will appear at entity/%.  That's essentially what makes it the "default"